# Question Regarding Equivalence of Definitions of Homomorphisms of Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism, free-groups

[image: The following is a proof regarding the equivalence of homomorphisms]

I'm new to group theory and was wondering what a "map" means in this context.
I was also hoping someone could explicitly state what the proof was conveying in words rather than symbols. Thank you.

Comment: A map here is just a function.  In some contexts, it may imply a homomorphism.

Comment: Since the universal algebraic definition clearly implies the textbook definition (which is just the first condition of the UA version), you need only prove that the textbook version implies the two extra properties in the UA version. What have you tried?

Comment: I wasn't familiar with all the notations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context a map is just a function. If you're trying to understand what an homomorphism is, maybe you can try an example. By definition, if $(G, *), (H, \cdot)$ are groups and $\phi:(G, *)\to (H, \cdot)$ is a map, then $\phi$ is said to be an homomorphism if it satisfies the property
$$ \phi(a * b)= \phi(a) \cdot \phi(b)$$
for all $a,b \in G.$ Consider, for example, the real numbers with the addittion $(\mathbf{R},+)$ and the nonzero real numbers with the product $(\mathbf{R}-\{0\}, \cdot).$ These are two (different) groups. Define $\phi:(\mathbf{R},+)\to (\mathbf{R}-\{0\}, \cdot)$ by
$$ \phi(x)=e^x.$$
Then, if $a,b \in (\mathbf{R},+),$ we have
$$ \phi(a+b)=e^{a+b}=e^a \cdot e^b = \phi(a) \cdot \phi(b),$$
so $\phi$ is an homomorphism of $(\mathbf{R},+)$ into $(\mathbf{R}-\{0\}, \cdot).$

Comment: Okay, I see it now, thank you so much for the clarification.

Comment: Could I e-mail you for further questions?

Comment: You can mail me at positron0802@mail.com

Comment: I have sent you an email. :)